# mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, postman

Recently bought a hosting service on hostgator and using cpanel i created a databe and users for it. I already put my IP in acess host.

When i try to connect the database from a remote acess by MySQL workbench i got it, but when i try to create a web service putting php files like connection.php and insert.php and try to send data by Postman, it show the error "mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user".

[image]

I already verify variables to connect, so they aren't incorret

How can i solve that problem?

**connection.php**

```
$hostname="myhost";
$user="myuser";
$password="mypassword";
$database="mydatabase";


$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);

?>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        require 'connection.php';
        createproduto();
    }

    function createproduto(){
        global $connect;

        $Usuarioscol = $_POST["Usuarioscol"];

        $query = "insert into Usuarios (Usuarioscol) values ('$Usuarioscol');";

        mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }

?>
```

That is for a future mobile app.

Comment: You should check the User on the mySQL database. Perhaps it is IP only access?

Comment: By the way you must use a secured way to insert data... check https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php